# Can we assume latent vectors are Euclidean?

Tags: neural-networks, latent-variable

I want to understand the mathematical nature of latent vectors, which I am pointing to general latent vectors which we can sample from an intermediate layer from a neural network.

Can we assume they are Euclidean?

Can we apply Euclidean geometry (e.g. distance/ area/ volume calculations) on latent vectors?

Comment: You can *always* adopt a Euclidean metric for any finite-dimensional (real) vector space.  The right question would be, *which one, if any, would be **useful** in a particular analysis?*

Answer (score 1):

They're n-dimensional vectors. Associating them with an Euclidean or non-Euclidean space/geometric rules will only be based on your assumptions. Therefore, yes.

Comment: Gunes, thanks for the answer! Then how should one judge whether the Euclidean or non-Euclidean assumption valid or invalid? I know people use distance to measure distance (Euclidean, cosine distance etc.) in latent space. I'm really curious if area/ volume can also be calculated + meaningful.

Comment: Validity would probably be an open problem. For example, as https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.06033.pdf mentions, the typical assumption for VAEs is Euclidean, but they argue with it, and propose a *better* mapping for a particular case. But, these typically boil down to assumptions and how they fit in with the objective and interpretations.